# Mark values with diffreent tag in sql

Tags: sql

I have one endpoint that is 7. I would like to few numbers 40,35,30,26,22,18,12 mark as completed.(This is an example. The value may be different)  and few numbers  13,17,21,27,32,38,43 mark as pending. (This is an example. The value may be different) Can we achieve by SQL statement? for number details, please find the image.

[image]

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Show the results you want.  I don't know if you want to update the table, set a flag, or just return rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your DBMS supports *Windowed Aggregates*:

```
with cte as
 ( select ID, point,
      -- find all rows after the latest 7 row
      sum(case when point = 7 then 1 end)
      over (order by ID DESC) as cumsum
   from tab
 )
select ID, point,
   case when point = 7 then 'endpoint'
        when cumsum is null then 'pending' -- no 7 after those IDs
        else 'completed'
   end 
from cte
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want everything before the first "7" as "completed" and the rest as "pending", then you can use window functions and cumulative logic.  One method is:

```
select t.*,
       (case when point = 7 then null
             when id < min(case when point = 7 then id end) over ()
             then 'complete'
             else 'pending'
        end) as mark
from t ;
```